# In Python, how do I grab the value of an entry in a python list created through a loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am writing Python code to pull data from a csv file and format it into geoJSON. I want to also grab single entries from the data to include in the properties of the geoJSON. For example, I convert a column of csv timestamps into geoJSON, and I also want to pull out the first and last timestamps in that list for the properties below:

```
   "properties": {
        "species": "racoon",
        "id": "12345",
        "first transmitted": "Aug 12, 2014",
        "last transmitted": "Nov 1, 2015"
}
```

I have written Python code that converts a column of timestamps from the csv to the geoJSON format:

```
# loop through the csv by row skipping the first
iter = 0

timevals = ""
for row in rawData:
    iter += 1
    if iter >= 2 and itemid == row[1]:
        rawtime = row[4]
        rawtime = rawtime.replace("T", " ")
        rawtime = rawtime.replace("Z", "")
        timevals += template_time % int( time.mktime(time.strptime(rawtime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') ))
```

This gives me the list of timestamps from the csv file formatted for my geoJSON file. Now I want to grab the first and last timestamp in that list. I altered it like this in order to try to grab the first:

```
# loop through the csv by row skipping the first
iter = 0

timevals = ""
for row in rawData:
    iter += 1
    if iter >= 2 and itemid == row[1]:
        rawtime = row[4]
        rawtime = rawtime.replace("T", " ")
        rawtime = rawtime.replace("Z", "")
        timeval = int( time.mktime(time.strptime(rawtime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') ))
        timevals += template_time % timeval
    startTime = timeval.iloc[0]
    print startTime
```

My error is:

```
startTime = timeval.iloc[0]
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

What is the way to write this?

**EDIT**
I got the startTime by initializing

```
startTime = ""
```

and then writing

```
if startTime == "":
    startTime = rawtime
```

so now I have the following, plus the endTime:

```
# loop through the csv by row skipping the first
iter = 0
startTime = ""

for row in rawData:
    iter += 1
    if iter >= 2 and itemid == row[1]:  # itemid
        rawtime = row[4]
        rawtime = rawtime.replace("T", " ")
        rawtime = rawtime.replace("Z", "")

        if startTime == "":
            startTime = rawtime

        endTime = rawtime
```

This ends up producing the first and final values, startTime and endTime, though its a bit of a trick and I was wondering if there was something more pythonic.

Comment: what are you expecting from iloc? iloc seems to be par of pandas library or does it exists on other objects? iloc is clearly not a member of int or string. see pandas doc: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

Comment: This edit is *much* better; thanks.  I'm updating my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification edit.  Can you easily hold the data in memory?  If so, you have a simple path: define a function for the conversion, then apply that only to the first and last items.

I'm assuming that you're skipping the first line because it's header information.  If so, then you don't really need to check for it explicitly; its 2nd entry won't match itemid, anyway.

```
def convert_time(rawtime):
    rawtime = row[4]
    rawtime = rawtime.replace("T", " ")
    rawtime = rawtime.replace("Z", "")

row_stream = [row in rawData if row[1] == itemid]
startTime = convert_time(row_stream[0])
endTime = convert_time(row_stream[-1])
```

If you have too much data for this to work, then trade the list comprehension for a generator, and let the Python run-time take care of the optimizations:

```
row_stream = (row in rawData if row[1] == itemid)
```

Comment: That is the concept, but when I add those two lines in place of the startTime line in my code, I get this error: 
 ` startTime = timevals[0]
IndexError: string index out of range`

Comment: Then we need some explanation on what these variables are supposed to be.  Looking higher in your code, it appears that this is *not* a list of timestamps as you stated.  Rather, *timevals* is a string to which you concatenate.  Have you added tracing print statements to show the values during the loop?  What do they show?  Perhaps you need to start *timevals* as a null list instead of a null string.  Can you perhaps supply your definition of rawData so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thanks Prune. I should have been more clear. The date/time in the csv is expressed in UTC (human readable), but I convert that to unix timestamp in the python code, so both formats are available. If I can grab the first and last entries from the csv, I would be getting the UTC format. If I wait till I convert these to a list of timestamps and grab the first and last from that, then the format would be unix timestamp.

Comment: Please edit this comment into your original posting and supply the requested traces (print statement output).  These are supposed to be part of the original posting.  See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for pointers.

Comment: *Much* better! Thanks!

Comment: FYI, you can push most of the work to Python with the generator expression too, while avoiding any meaningful memory storage. Initialize the `row_stream` to the generator expression, then do: `start_time = next(row_stream)` (will raise `StopIteration` if no entries found instead of `IndexError` of `list` version), then do `end_time = next(iter(deque(row_stream, 1)), start_time)` to slurp the rest of the generator (storing only most recent match), and return either last match, or the `start_time` if the whole generator only had one match (following behavior of list index at `[0]` and `[-1]`).

Comment: To be clear, `deque` is from `collections` module. Also, runtime should be essentially identical (ever so slightly slower for times when list comp output is small, faster when list comp output would be huge) thanks to `deque` being C level (just like `list`), with peak memory being fixed (instead of possibly huge with list comp).